# Django hash integrate with legacy database

Tags: django, hash, passwords, bcrypt, django-authentication

I am working with django on a mysql legacy database. I have integrated everything but passwords. The legacy database is storing the passwords this way
`$2a$10$Pdg3h8AVZ6Vl3X1mMKgQDuMriv8iysnValEa5YZO3j9pEboLrOBUK` and django reads only if the same hash has the `bcrypt$` prefix `bcrypt$$2a$10$Pdg3h8AVZ6Vl3X1mMKgQDuMriv8iysnValEa5YZO3j9pEboLrOBUK` . How do I make django authenticate users by reading first example hash?

And why django is adding the prefix to the password?

**UPDATE**
I have added the model backend

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from users.models import TbUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef, Q

UserModel = get_user_model()


class BaseBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        return None

    def get_user_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        return set()

    def get_group_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        return set()

    def get_all_permissions(self, user_obj, obj=None):
        return {
            *self.get_user_permissions(user_obj, obj=obj),
            *self.get_group_permissions(user_obj, obj=obj),
        }

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        return perm in self.get_all_permissions(user_obj, obj=obj)


class ModelBackend(BaseBackend):
    """
    Authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Authentication start")
        print("User: ", username, " Password: ", password)
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.password.startswith('bcrypt'):
                u = user
            else:
                u = UserModel(password=f'bcrypt${user.password}')
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Authentication prefix adding...")
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> NO-PREFIX: ", user.password)
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> WITH-PREFIX: ",
                      f'bcrypt${user.password}')
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> CHECKING PASSWORD NO-PREFIX: ",
                      user.check_password(password))
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> CHECKING PASSWORD WITH-PREFIX: ",
                      user.check_password(f'bcrypt${user.password}'))
                #user = UserModel(password=f'bcrypt${user.password}')
            if u.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        """
        Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
        that attribute are allowed.
        """
        is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
        return is_active or is_active is None
```

the settings.py is using this authentication backend

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'users.backends.ModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

and when django checks the password it throws the following error

```
File "\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "\auth\users\backends.py", line 74, in authenticate
    if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
  File "\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 112, in check_password
    return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)
  File "\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 49, in check_password
    must_update = hasher_changed or preferred.must_update(encoded)
  File "\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py", line 443, in must_update
    return int(rounds) != self.rounds
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2b'
```

I have used a part of this implementation https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/backends.py

**TESTING**

```
>>> from users.models import TbUser
>>> from django.contrib.auth import check_password
>>> user = TbUser.objects.get(username="Gastro")
>>> user
<TbUser: Gastro>
>>> ps = user.password
>>> ps_bc = "bcrypt$" + ps
>>> ps_bc
'bcrypt$$2a$10$rA59QU2GsWR4v6hugdYhruxY0bgZYVLv6ncxRe3BiDJMEpK0A0huW'
>>> check_password("111111", ps_bc)
True
>>> check_password("111111", ps)
False
>>> user.check_password("111111") 
False
```

Comment: It uses a prefix since the first part is the *algorithm* that is used. The hashes in Django have the form `<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>`

Comment: https://qvault.io/cryptography/bcrypt-step-by-step/ , from here I see that its not using the bcrypt$(and its's bcrypt without using the prefix) , and the algorithm is that portion between the first two dollar signs

Comment: but that article is completely in the style that `bcrypt$` is used as *the* encrypted form. From the moment two or more algorithms are candidate, you need to prefix it to know *what* algorithm should be used.

Comment: is it only for django required to use prefix? if no then why the database is storing pswords without prefix?

Comment: well the passwords are stored by the other application I guess, so you can make modifications to that other (legacy)  application, to write (and read) it with the `bcrypt$` prefix.

Comment: unfortunately I do not have access to that source code. I just need to make it work with django. ))

Comment: well all applications that allow multiple hashing algorithms, will somehow need to store the algorithm that has been used.

Comment: but since I know what algorithm the legacy app is using, why just not implementing it in django to work the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django first specifies the *hashing* algorithm that is used, since it can for example use different hashing algorithms for each user.

There are basically two ways to solve this:

1. changing the passwords in the database; or
2. make a (slightly) different authentication backend that will prepend it with the password.

## Option 1: update the password

You can update the records in bulk with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

MyModel.objects.update(
    password=Concat(Value('bcrypt$'), F('password'))
)
```

This will thus update the password field (if the passwords are stored in another field, you use that field name) by prepending `'bcrypt$'` to the hashes.

## Option 2: make a custom authentication method

We can subclass the `ModelBackend` and slightly rewrite this to:

```
# app_name/backends.py

django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyModelBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        if username is None or password is None:
            return
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.password.startswith('bcrypt'):
                u = user
            else:
                u = UserModel(password=f'bcrypt_sha256${user.password}')
            if u.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
```

We can then register this backend in the [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#authentication-backends):

```
# settings.py

# …

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'app_name.backends.MyModelBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]

# …
```

Comment: the database is used by another application, I need a solution that makes django read and also store passwords that way

Comment: @Brat: perhaps you can make two fields a `password` and a `djangopassword` that then has the `bcrypt$` part.

Comment: yes, i did it this way but I want both applications to use the same password column in the mysql table. So users from another app can login to the django app.

Comment: @Brat: you can also try to implement a custom authentication backend that will prepend this. I shared a solution, although at the moment I can not test it.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion, take a look please at the problem! big thanks

Comment: @Brat: are you sure the passwords in the database start with a `$2a`? and not simply `2a`?

Comment: yes `$2a$10$Pdg3h8AVZ6Vl3X1mMKgQDuMriv8iysnValEa5YZO3j9pEboLrOBUK` this is a full password hash

Comment: @Brat: what if you prefix with `bcrypt_sha256$`? instead of `bcrypt$`.

Comment: it worked! thank you UPDATE: did not work :DD

Comment: the password that I have tried had the prefix already, sorry

Comment: @Brat: so you use `user.password = f'bcrypt_sha256${user.password}'`? Are there items in the database that have this prefix? In that case we need to write some `if` logic to prevent that for items that are already prefixed.

Comment: i see when I login, the model backend changes the password in the database, it prepends the prefix. And the second time it prepends again. I need to add prefix somewhere else, at the password check

Comment: that's why there was that error with '2b'

Comment: @Brat: hmmm, what if we do this with a new `UserModel` object that we do *not* save to the database, see edit. This will require the passwords *not* to start with `bcrypt_sha256$...`, so you probably have to revert some of edits in the database

Comment: take a look at my tests, strange things :D check password in django shell returns true, and in app false

Comment: is the user.check_password() different than django's auth check?

Comment: @Brat: the `authenticate` will normally fetch the user that has the given username/email/... and then call `.check_password` on that user, which will call the `check_password` function of the authentication module.

Comment: I have updated the testing so its more clear now what happens

Comment: @Brat: did you undo all the changes Django made to the passwords? Because the updated authenticator, will normally *not* change the passwords in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233579/discussion-between-brat-and-willem-van-onsem).